# Python. Обработка события получения данных при программировании TCP сокетов

Tags: python, сокет, события

Нужна помощь.
Есть клиентский сокет, который отправляет данные при получении команды от сервера.
При получении одной из команд клиент должен отправлять одни и те же данные ( неважно какие, хоть строку) постоянно, пока от сервера не поступит команда на остановку этого процесса. Как это сделать?

```
from socket import *
import sys
import math



host = 'localhost'
port = 1111
addr = (host, port)


while True:
    tcp_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM) #создание сокета
    try:
        tcp_socket.connect(addr) #подключение к серверному сокету
    except Exception:
        continue
    while True:
        comand = tcp_socket.recv(10000000)
        comand = bytes.decode(comand)
        print(comand)
        if comand == '111222':
            s = []
            t = 0.002
            j = 0
            for i in range(4000):
                x = 2 * 3.14 * 50 * t
                y = round(40 * math.sin(x), 3)
                s.append(y)
                j += 1
                t = 0.00015 * j 
            dod = s
            print(dod)
            data = str(dod)
            data = str.encode(data)
            tcp_socket.send(data)
            break
        else:
            break
        break
```

Answer (score 2):

Клиент подключается к серверу, получает команду (заканчивается новой строкой:  `'\n'`) и начинает отсылать строки, пока не поступит команда остановки (не тестировал):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import socket
import threading

def send_loop(write, done):
    while not done.is_set():
        write(b'something\n')

done = None
with socket.create_connection((host, port)) as sock, sock.makefile() as file:
    for command in map(str.rstrip, file):
        if command == 'start' and done is None:
            done = threading.Event()
            threading.Thread(target=send_loop, args=[sock.sendall, done], daemon=True).start()
        elif command == 'stop' and done is not None:
            done.set()
            done = None
```

чтобы прервать цикл, используется `done` событие. Три состояния:

1. `done is None`: клиент ничего не посылает, ожидает команду `'start'`
2. `not done.is_set()`: клиент посылает данные, ожидает команду `'stop'`
3. `done.is_set()`: дочерний поток завершается, выходя из цикла. Переходим в 1-ое состояние, устанавливая `done = None`.